# Suck-ups,suck up to

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

Are the phrases used? I mean it's slang.......
"Suck up"https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/suck+up

> 1. (verb) To habitually offer flattery in the hope of gaining favor; to behave sycophantically.
>
>    - *Stop sucking up just to try to get an A. Just study like everyone else.*
> 2. (noun) A person who habitually offers flattery in the hope of gaining favor; a sycophant. In this usage, the phrase is usually hyphenated.
>
>    - *Billy is always complimenting the teacher on her hair. What a suck-up.*

"Suck up to" https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/suck-up-to-sb

> "Why do you think he offered to take all that work home?"
>
> "Oh, he's just sucking up to the boss."

Are these used? And what are it's alternatives?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, they are used. But it does not sound nice.

An alternative with the same meaning, but with nicer words is: [to kiss up](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/kiss+up).

> kiss up (slang) = To habitually offer flattery in the hope of gaining favor; to behave sycophantically.
>
> - *Stop kissing up just to try to get an A. Just study like everyone else.*